# copy-of select name

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have this data in source XML:

```
<Firma ID_FIRMY="15" ROLE_FIRMY="O " KOD_FIRMY="Tomášov">
```

This is my XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">                      
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root/Firma">
<MoneyData> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="@ID_FIRMY"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@KOD_FIRMY"/>
</MoneyData>                         
</xsl:template>                                 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MoneyData ID_FIRMY="15" KOD_FIRMY="Tomášov"/>
```

But I need this output: (change names..)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MoneyData KodAgendy="15" HospRokOd="Tomášov"/>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write templates to transform the attributes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">                      
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="root/Firma">
<MoneyData> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</MoneyData>                         
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="Firma/@ID_FIRMY">
  <xsl:attribute name="KodAgendy"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Firma/@KOD_FIRMY">
  <xsl:attribute name="HospRokOd"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@ROLE_FIRMY"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```